# Has vs. might not have been?

Tags: tense, present-perfect, subjunctives

Here’s the two sentences:

> This **has not** always been the case.
>
> This **might not have** always been the case.

Obviously, using "has" in the first and "have" in the second is correct. I know that. But, what is the rule that says that is it the case? The only different between the two is “might not” but I am just curious as to what rule established this usage.

Answer (score 1):

It is categorized as [Modal verbs](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/modal-verbs).
If you are hesitated to use either has or have, Modal verbs are always follow by have. You can find more information about its usage with "have" [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/modals-have).